# Magento install takes a while from configuration to admin screen - normal?

Tags: magento

I just started using magento 1.7, and on my localhost when I enter stuff on the `configuration` page (mysql db stuff etc.) and click `next` to proceed to `Create admin account`, it works and proceeds but it takes a few minutes.

Is this normal stuff to you guys as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vojislav - it depends on the performance of the server that you are running on the localhost (and the later mostly depends on the strength of your machine). If, for example you are running your magento on apache+mysql server (or precompiled apache+mysql with software like XAMPP) that installed on not very strong computer, the DB step may take few minutes (what was actually in my case).

Comment: Yep, my machine is not that strong, I am using EasyPHP, similar to XAMPP. I also use joomla extensively and it's normal, I know Magento is bigger but still...this is ridiculous. I hope it won't behave this way once I upload it to a live server, really irritating.

Comment: Yes, but I believe that the installation speed is not that important for you. The most important is the performance after the installation, no? And it is for sure faster than the installation, especially when the cache is enabled.

Comment: It's not as slow as installation but I think it's much slower than it can be. Hopefully new hardware will sort it out. How can I enable automatic caching ?

Comment: After the Magento installation, go to the backend, then System->Cache Management. There, you should ensure that all the cache types are on status "enabled". If not, just check all the checkboxes, choose "Enable" in actions drop down, and click "Submit".

Comment: But you should be aware that each time you add products, changes system configurations, install extensions and more - you will have to flush the cache to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not.
Is your MySql server on the same machine? 
This sounds like either a latency issue, or a really slow server...
Try enabling cache in the backend and see if that helps